# React route: NavLink and Redirect not working, i need to reload the page to see the contents

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

NavLink and Redirect is not working for some reason. I need to reload the page to see the contents.

```js
                <Router>
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path = {"/u/"+uID+"/music"}>
                            <MusicContent
                                musics = {musics} 
                                name = {name} 
                                play = {play} 
                                uID = {uID} 
                                userName = {currentUserName} 
                                pfp= {pfp} 
                                user = {user}
                            />
                        </Route>
                    </Switch>
                </Router>
                <Redirect to = {"/u/"+uID+"/music"} />
```

when i go to `http://localhost:3000/u/RXVcSX0fY7dAgEMEfrt7oEzqiUF2/` it redirects me to `http://localhost:3000/u/RXVcSX0fY7dAgEMEfrt7oEzqiUF2/music` but the contents arent renders. And when i refresh the page, the content Renders. I tried it with NavLink too.

```js
NavLink to = {"/u/"+uID+"/music"}><button><span>Music</span></button></NavLink>
```

same thing happens.

But when i manually type the url `http://localhost:3000/u/RXVcSX0fY7dAgEMEfrt7oEzqiUF2/music` this in the browser the content renders up

If you wanna take a look at my `<MusicContent />`

```js
//this is my musicContent

function MusicContent(props){
    let musics = props.musics;
    let name = props.name;
    let uID = props.uID;
    let currentUserName = props.userName
    let pfp = props.pfp
    let user = props.user
    function play(event){
        props.play(event)
    }
    return(
                <div class = "music-content-container">
                    <div class = "music-box">
                        <div class = "user-musics">
                                {musics && musics.map((name, i)=>{   
                                    return(
                                        <Fragment key = {i}>
                                                <MusicPreview 
                                                    name = {name} 
                                                    play = {play} 
                                                    uID = {uID} 
                                                    userName = {currentUserName} 
                                                    pfp= {pfp} 
                                                    user = {user}
                                                />
                                        </Fragment>
                                    )
                                })}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>  
    )
}

export default MusicContent
```

Comment: You should use `Redirect` in the `Switch` like `<Route><Redirect to={'the path'}/></Route>"`. Make sure to define this Route at the last